# OS X 10.10.4 Yosemite, has the default PATH changed?

Tags: macos, bash, homebrew, path

Today I had to configure a new macbook, running `10.10.3` out of the box and immediately upgraded to `10.10.4`.

After installing `homebrew` I went to configure the default `PATH`, and opened `/etc/paths`.

I found that it contained:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

that is, `/usr/local/bin` is at the top. This is not what I was expecting, and what I know should be the default.

Has the default changed? I reviewed the Homebrew installation script, and it doesn't seem to change `/etc/paths`. I also `stat`'ed the file, and it doesn't seem to have been changed.

So, is this the new default PATH order in OS X?

Answer (score 2):

My `/etc/paths` has the same content on 10.10.4 and has a timestamp of "Sep  9  2014" so it has been like that for quite some time now.

Basically it makes sense to place `/usr/local/bin` on top because that way binaries installed locally take precedence over the standard versions.

Comment: Thank you, the timestamp on that new macbook is the same as yours. Yes, I know it makes sense, but the old default was to have `/usr/local/bin` at the bottom of the list, and in fact I'm used to manually modify `/etc/paths` on new macs for this reason.